# Проблема с загрузкой Windows10 с флешки

Tags: windows, windows-10

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста, что нужно сделать, если при установке windows10 с флешки, выбирая в биосе флешку на которой винда записана , экран выдает такие рисунки

Comment: выбросить флешку. Или компьютер.

Comment: Порнобсорка или официалка? Чем писал?